# e.which codes for CTRL + A and CTRL + E

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anybody please tell me e.which codes for key press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.

Also please tell me where i can find these values, i tried searching google but no appropriate results and i dont want shortcuts plugin for simple needs.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Ctrl + Key Combination](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2009/06/16/ctrl-key-combination-simple-jquery-plugin/)
simple example:

```
if(e.keyCode == key.charCodeAt(0) && isCtrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpful?

http://www.scottklarr.com/topic/126/how-to-create-ctrl-key-shortcuts-in-javascript/

If 'S' is 83, then A = 65, right? And E=69?

Comment: according to me the keycodes are different, if i am wrong please rectify me.

Comment: E=68, seems like I can't count :P

Comment: @Victor- E=69, your A is just off. you can always refer to an ascii table for verfication

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery UI Core (ui.core.js) you have translations for common key codes.

```
$.keyCode = { 
    ...
    ENTER: 13, 
    ...
};
```

just check there the key codes, you don't have to include this file.